# Excel VBA - Copy module from a protected VBA project into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, password-protection

**My problem** with Excel's `VBA code protection`:

In my current project, I wrote some VBA code (in WB1) that shall produce a new workbook (WB2). In this new workbook, a button (B2) is created. This button shall execute some code, when pressed. The macro that shall be executed is copied from the original workbook (WB1). This all works fine, when the VBA code in the original workbook (WB1) is not protected.
However, when I add protection to the VBA code in the original workbook, the module that contains the macro is not copied into the new workbook (WB2). And thus the button (B2) has no functionality.

**My question:** Has anyone of you run into the same problem and is there an other solution than removing the protection from the original workbook's VBA code?

[image: I tried to summarize the workflow and the problem in this picture]

Comment: Suggest to use a template workbook, instead of recreating the workbook.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! Sadly, it is not possible to work with templates in my use case since they have to be stored "somewhere". Maybe I was not clear in my question. WB2 is not a recreation of WB1. WB2 has complete new functionlity. And besides this functionlity it shall have a makro (M2) that is executed when button B2 is pressed. And this makro code is provided in WB1 to be copied to WB2 when created. Maybe a workaround would be to simply create a new module in Wb2 and wirte the makro code as `string` into the module..